# Не передаются данные с контроллера в Vue

Tags: vue.js

Ничего не понимаю! Уже сижу второй день и никак не могу понять, почему не отображаются данные на фронте.
В контроллере проверял результат есть. А на фронте нет. В точки останова в самом скрипте не проваливается вообще и это очень странно. Никаких ошибок тоже нет. 
Прошу помогите пожалуйста понять в чем дело! Спасибо! 
Вот что у меня на Front-end:

```
            @* Это начальная страница. Страница регистрации и авторизации *@
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title> NodovERP | Главная </title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="~/css/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    @* меню хидера *@
                    @* nav - помещает навигацию сайта и отдельные ссылки *@
                    <div role="navigation">
                        @* элементы меню *@
                        <div class="container">
                            @* реализация бургера при маленьком экране *@
                            <div class="navbar-header header">
                                @* логотип и слоган *@
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <h1 class="headerTitle"> NodovERP </h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                @* data-target="#navbarCollapse" - при нажатии на кнопку мы будем отображать блок с id = navbarCollapse, т.е наше меню *@
                                @*<button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                                        <span class="sr-only"> Toogle navigation </span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
                                    </button>*@
                            </div>
                            @* navbar-right - прижимает навигацию к правому краю *@
                            @* здесь id="navbarCollapse" нужен для того, чтобы на мобильных устройствах появился бургер с вертикальным меню *@
                            @*<div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">*@
                            @* список меню *@
                            @* class="active" - означает активную вкладку меню, которая изначально подсвечивается *@
                            @*<ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                        <li class="active"> @Html.ActionLink("Главная", "mainPage", "Home") </li>
                                        <li> @Html.ActionLink("Фильмы", "filmsShow", "Home") </li>
                                        <li> @Html.ActionLink("Сериалы", "pageSerials", "Home") </li>
                                        <li> @Html.ActionLink("Рейтинг фильмов", "pageRating", "Home") </li>
                                        <li> @Html.ActionLink("Контакты", "pageContacts", "Home") </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            @* пустой блок для отступа слева *@
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>
            @* форма регистрации и авторизации *@
            <div class="col-lg-4 panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading"><div class="sidebar-header"> Вход </div></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="idLogin" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Логин">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="idPassword" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Пароль" v-model="password">
                        </div>
                        <button id="idSignIn" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" v-on:click="onPress"> Вход </button>
                        <button id="idRegistration" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning pull-left"> Регистрация </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            @* пустой блок для отступа справа *@
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>
            @* отправляем на бэк введенные пользователем данные для проверки в БД *@
            <script>
                new Vue({
                    el: "#idSignIn",
                    methods: {
                        onPress: () => {
                            return $.ajax({
                                url: '/Users/checkLogAndPas/',
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    USER_LOGIN: document.getElementById('idLogin').value,
                                    USER_PASSWORD: document.getElementById('idPassword').value
                                },
                                success: (event) => {
                                    debugger;
                                    console.log("OK", event);
                                    //document.write("Успешно", data);
                                    //console.log("Успешно", data);
                                },
                                fail: (event) => {
                                    debugger;
                                    console.log("Error", event);
                                    //document.write("Неудача", data);
                                    //console.log("Ошибка", data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Вот что на Back-end: в контроллере

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using NodovERP.Models;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows;
    // Здесь бизнес-логика работы с пользователями
    namespace NodovERP.Controllers {
        public class UsersController : Controller {
            public string result = "";
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult checkLogAndPas(Users user) {
                string connectionString = @"data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=NodovERPDB;integrated security=True;
                MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
                using (SqlConnection strConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                    try {
                        string comandDB = "SELECT * From Users WHERE USER_LOGIN = '" + user.USER_LOGIN + "' AND USER_PASSWORD = '" + user.USER_PASSWORD + "'";   //строка запроса к БД
                        SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand(comandDB, strConn);   //команда к БД
                        strConn.Open();
                        //сравниваем с данными в БД 
                        if (check.ExecuteScalar() != null) {
                            string sText = user.USER_LOGIN;   //для передачи логина пользователя
                            //Close();
                            //strConn.Close();
                            //return Json("OK");
                            result = "1";
                        }
                        //проверяем все ли поля заполненны
                        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.USER_LOGIN) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.USER_PASSWORD))) {
                            //return Json(user);
                            result = "2";
                        }
                        else {
                            //если данные не верны
                            result = "3";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        return Json(user);
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (strConn.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
                            strConn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return Json(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

С моделью у меня все ок. Ее код скину для полноты картины.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NodovERP.Models {
    // Класс, представляющий объекты, которые будут хранится в БД, содержащие логины, пароли и почту пользователей
    public class Users {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string USER_LOGIN { get; set; }
        public string USER_PASSWORD { get; set; }
        public string USER_EMAIL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. На какой строчке установлен брейкпойнт, куда не проваливаемся... Давайте так. Есть фронт, есть бек. С фронта ajax-запрос уходит на контроллер? (смотрим в браузере на закладке сетевая активность) Приходит в контроллер? (ставим бряку в контроллере)? Данные назад отдаются? (смотрим в отладчике браузера) На какой стадии ошибка?

Comment: Да, конечно. На любые вопросы с радостью отвечу. ajax-запрос на бэк уходит нормально. Точки останова в контроллере ставил и получал нужный результат (смотрел через окно интерпретации). На фронте не проваливаюсь ни в success, ни в fail. А должен.
Ошибки нет. Тупик в том, что не могу понять, почему не проваливаюсь на фронте и соответственно фронт не выводит даже простые логи в консоли об успехе.

Comment: Странно, в первый раз такой вижу. А добавьте не только success и error, но и [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42229704/5752652). Хотя если ни то, ни тот не вызвался - то и вряд ли complete будет. И кстати, success на вход не event, а data.

Comment: Поменял на data. Результат тот же. Кстати. Только что заметил, что в нетворке нет вообще моего запроса POST контроллеру но данные ему приходят).
Проваливается лишь если поставить точку в самом конце скрипта. И то не всегда срабатывает. Он как бы пытается провалиться, но точки сразу сбрасываются все и ни ошибок ничего.

Comment: Ага, становится понятнее. Запросов должно быть два, один xhr второй настоящий POST.

Comment: Если в конце скрипта ставлю точку останова, то раз через раз бывает возвращает результат в логе консоли. 
Ну запроса ни одного в нетворке не вижу связанные с контроллером.
Запрос POST я так понимаю отработает и появится в нетворке лишь после того, как фронт получит данные с бэка. То есть когда провалится на фронте в мои логи.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то будет полезным, то проблема оказалась банальной. Проблема заключалась не в скрипте, а в разметке в строках

```
<button id="idSignIn" type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" v-on:click="onPress"> Вход </button>
<button id="idRegistration" type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left"> Регистрация </button>
```

Нужно было поменять type="submit" на type="button", потому что если ставить type="submit" когда отправляем ajax-запрос, то будет происходить двойное обновление страницы. И второе обновление будет срезать отправку данных. В этом любой сможет убедиться, если детально просмотрит вкладку нетворк.